# Hibernate mapping to manage bidirectional relationship using intermediate table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have an object hierarchy that is as follows.

Party > inherited by > Organization and Person
Organization > inherited by > Customer, Vendor
Person > inherited by > Contact

In the database I have the following tables
Party, Customer, Vendor, Contact. All of them have a corresponding row in Party table.

Contact belongs to either Vendor or Customer. I have a field on the Contact table for org_party_id. However, since the organization can be either a Customer or Vendor I need to be able to look at different tables.

Is there a way to map this in hibernate? Or, a better way to manage it in DB/ hibernate?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new table called **Organization** with 2 fields **org_party_id** and **org_party_type**.

each **org_party_id** whould match match a **Customer.id** if the **org_party_type** is CUSTOMER, or a **Vendor.id** if the **org_party_type** is VENDOR.

Change the mappings of **Customer** and **Vendor** to be a Subclasses of Organization. (See the [reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-subclass) .  Set **org_party_type** as the *discriminator*.

Now, set the mapping of **Contact** to point to Organization.

This will abstract out the organization part of **Customers** and **Vendors**, so that you can deal with them consistently.  You might want to create an **Organization** interface in your code as well so the abstraction is consistent.

**UPDATED**
Based on your comments, (and be rereading the question), it looks like a joined-subquery is your best bet.  This would mean that you don't really need to add org_party_type, as the subclasses are joined by the ID.  Like so:

```
   <class name="Party" table="PARTY">
            <id name="org_party_id" column="uid" type="long">
                    <generator class="hilo"/>
            </id>

            <!-- other PARTY properties -->

            <joined-subclass name="Customer" table="CUSTOMER">
                <key column="customer_id"/>
                <property name="name" type="string"/>

                <!-- other CUSTOMER properties -->

            </joined-subclass>

            <joined-subclass name="Vendor" table="VENDOR">
                <key column="vendor_id"/>
                <property name="name" type="string"/>

                <!-- other VENDOR properties -->

            </joined-subclass>
    </class>
```

_

Comment: Updated - use a regular subclass rather than a joined-subclass.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I merge the Customer and Vendor table into Organization table or create an additional Organization table? I cannot do the former. If it is the later, how is the Organization table different from the Party table. I could just add a type on the Party table.

Comment: You're right--it is no different from Party.  Add the type to Party and then make Vendor and Customer subclasses.

Comment: Thinking some more about it, given that you've got Party already, you're probably best off with a joined-subclass, which would eliminate the need for a discriminator.  I'll update above.